# How to test and mock mongodb with flask?

Tags: python, mongodb, unit-testing, flask, testing

I'm trying to do a test of an endpoint post, which sends information in json to a mongo database.

How do I perform a unit test in this case? How can I mock mongo to have a momentary database?

Below is my code. Note that if I don't have the mongo connected, I get the error that it was not possible to send the data, which is notorious. My question is, how can I perform this test by mocking the mongo?

```
import json
import unittest

from api import app

app.testing = True  # set our application to testing mode


class TestApi(unittest.TestCase):

    with app.test_client() as client:   

        # send data as POST form to endpoint
        sent = {
            "test1": 1,
            "test2": 1,
            "test3": 1
        }

        mimetype = 'application/json'

        headers = {
            'Content-Type': mimetype,
        }

        #fixtures
        result = client.post(
            '/post/',
            data=json.dumps(sent), headers=headers, environ_base={'REMOTE_ADDR': 'locahost'})

    def test_check_result_server_have_expected_data(self):
        # check result from server with expected data
        self.assertEqual(self.result.json,  self.sent)

    def test_check_content_equals_json(self):
        # check content_type == 'application/json'
        self.assertEqual(self.result.content_type, self.mimetype)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    unittest.main()
```

My api calls mongo in that way:

```
@api.route('/post/')
class posting(Resource):
    @api.doc(responses={200: 'Success', 500: 'Internal Server Error', 400: 'Bad Request'})
    @api.doc(body=fields, description="Uploads data")
    @api.expect(fields, validate=True)
    def post(self):
        try:
            mongodb_helper.insert_metric(name="ODD", timestamp=request.json["timestamp"], 
            metric_type="field1", value=request.json["field1"])
            
            return ("Data saved successfully", 201)

        except:
            return ("Could not create new data", 500)
```

Thanks,

Comment: How does your app connect to the MongoDB database? You would have to instrument it to connect to a temporary database when it's being tested.

Comment: (Or, if you don't want to actually save data to the database at all, you would mock the MongoDB layer, however you've implemented it.)

Comment: Exactly, I need to mock the MongoDB layer. But my question is, how to do this?

Comment: The same way you'd mock any module or function – since you're using `unittest`, probably a patcher from `unittest.patch`: https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#the-patchers

Comment: Sorry, but I still can't understand. How will I make a patch for the mongo since my API only sends the data to the mongo? I updated the code above with API code.

Comment: Patch `mongodb_helper.insert_metric` to not actually post things, then check in your test that the mock object you patched in had been called.

Comment: But in that case, how am I going to verify that I sent to mongo the correct parameters (teste1, teste2...)? Could you please give an example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an example of using `unittest.mock.Mock` and the `patch` context manager. You will of course need to replace `"__main__.insert_metric"` with something more suitable.

```
import unittest.mock

# Function to be mocked


def insert_metric(**kwargs):
    raise ValueError("this should never get called")


# Function to be tested


def post(data):
    insert_metric(
        name="ODD", timestamp=data["timestamp"], metric_type="field1", value=data["field1"]
    )


# Test case


def test_post():
    insert_metric_mock = unittest.mock.MagicMock()
    with unittest.mock.patch("__main__.insert_metric", insert_metric_mock):
        post({"timestamp": 8, "field1": 9})
    print(insert_metric_mock.mock_calls)  # for debugging
    insert_metric_mock.assert_called_with(
        name="ODD", timestamp=8, metric_type="field1", value=9
    )


if __name__ == "__main__":
    test_post()
```

This prints out

```
[call(metric_type='field1', name='ODD', timestamp=8, value=9)]
```

and doesn't raise an assertion error.